# Как отобразить результат XmlDiff?

Tags: c#

Использую nuget библиотеку Microsoft.XmlDiffPatch, получаю результат сравнения двух  xml с помощью XmlDiff.Compare(), как мне отобразить в html этот результат? Как его тобразить с помощью xslt?

Comment: Я сам не глядел, но нагуглил вот такое [XML Diff & Patch GUI Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24313)

Comment: вот [тут](https://github.com/microsoft/XmlNotepad) также есть возможность сравнивать 2 XML, но какой либой они это делают я хз